# text analysis with merging html files

Tags: r, text

I have 3 different text files and their names are txt1 txt2 txt3:

```
txt1 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2010_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1")  
txt2 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2011_tarihli_Diyarbak%C4%B1r_mitinginde_yapt%C4%B1%C4%9F%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fma")  
txt3 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_%C5%9Eubat_2011_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1 " )
```

Now I am trying to create a unique html text file to analyse all these as they are one file. 
Any idea how can I create one unique html text file with different html text files?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this is about as unclear as your "[Using multiple texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424424/using-multiple-texts)" question and will likely result in the same thing that happened there. What you want is very unclear, esp the description of the output or an example of the output.

Comment: What I want is, creating a long text that consist of these three texts. Like: textonly = txt1+txt2+txt3. So how can I create it? I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path, what about this:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

txt1 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2010_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1")  
txt2 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2011_tarihli_Diyarbak%C4%B1r_mitinginde_yapt%C4%B1%C4%9F%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fma")  
txt3 <- read_html("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_%C5%9Eubat_2011_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1 " )

# first link
 df1<- txt1 %>%
    html_nodes('#mw-content-text p') %>%  #choose the text
    html_text() %>%                       
    t() %>%                               # transpose
    data.frame() %>%                      # as data.frame
    unite()                               # melt all the cell in one text
```

Same thing for the second and third links:

```
 df2<- txt2 %>%
   html_nodes('#mw-content-text p') %>%
   html_text() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>%unite()

 df3<- txt3 %>%
   html_nodes('#mw-content-text p') %>%
   html_text() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>%unite()
```

Last you put all in one cell for example :

```
 df_total <- cbind(df1,df2,df3) %>% unite()
```

EDIT:

You can create a loop that parses all the pages in a vector of links:

```
txt1 <- ("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2010_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1")  
txt2 <- ("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_Haziran_2011_tarihli_Diyarbak%C4%B1r_mitinginde_yapt%C4%B1%C4%9F%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fma")  
txt3 <- ("https://tr.wikisource.org/wiki/Recep_Tayyip_Erdo%C4%9Fan%27%C4%B1n_1_%C5%9Eubat_2011_tarihli_AK_Parti_grup_toplant%C4%B1s%C4%B1_konu%C5%9Fmas%C4%B1 " )

url <- c(txt1, txt2, txt3)        # all the urls

# the loop that scrapes and put in a list
dfList <- lapply(url, function(i) 
{
  swimwith <- read_html(i)
  swdf <- swimwith %>%
    html_nodes('#mw-content-text p') %>%
    html_text()%>%                       
    t() %>%                              
    data.frame() %>%                      
    unite()     
})

# from list to df
finaldf1 <- do.call(cbind, dfList) %>% unite()
```

Comment: I thank you so much. The logic is very clear for me. Is it okay if I ask one more question to you? If I have more than 3 texts, for example 50, is there any other easy way to make them united?

Comment: You are welcome! You can put it in a loop, as put in the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! @s_t